# Is this right way to call coroutine method in Tornado framework?

Tags: python, tornado, tornado-motor

I have WebSocketHandler in my Tornado application.
I am not sure is this a right way to make code asynchronous.

```
class MyHandler(WebSocketHandler):
    def open(self):
        do something ...
        self.my_coroutine_method()

    @gen.coroutine
    def my_coroutine_method(self):
        user = yield db.user.find_one() # call motor asynchronous engine
        self.write_message(user)
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is correct. However, in some cases simply calling a coroutine without yielding can cause exceptions to be handled in unexpected ways, so I recommend using `IOLoop.current().spawn_callback(self.my_coroutine_method)` when calling a coroutine from a non-coroutine like this.